# get_absolute_url() using app hook in Django

Tags: django, url, django-models, get, absolute

I have the following Django model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug    = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    active  = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return '/' +self.slug
```

And I attached it to a page using this apphook:

```
class ProductApphook(CMSApp):
    name = _("Products Apphook")
    urls = ["product.urls"]
apphook_pool.register(ProductApphook)
```

My question is about the get_absolute_url function: it will return an invalid url, since the slug of the page where this apphook is attached will not be prepended to the absolute_url in the models get_absolute_url function.
Is there a way to make the get_absolute_url function return the correct url? I'm particularly interested in this because the 'Preview' function in the admin doesn't work for the above setup

I'm not quite sure this is possible, e.g. what if the apphook is attached to multiple pages?

Comment: You should consider adding a 'u' before the '/': return u'/' + self.slug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend creating a named url in your urls.py, and then reversing the url in your get_absolute_url function. See the Django docs for [reverse()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse).